# A error was found when clicked the "apply code change" at VS2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005

When I debug a program using VS2005, and I click "apply code change" to edit the program, I get this error "Microsoft Visual Studio has encountered an internal error" error code LCID 1033

Comment: You haven't added a picture, also it's better to post your error as text/code in your question when possible rather than an image

Comment: I also want to add the picture, however, it looks like I don't have the right to add it....

Comment: So paste the error as text please